# Does something like is_rest() exist

Tags: rest-api

I am starting a bit with the REST API. If I am not completly mislead, the `init` action hook is also executed when its a REST API request. Now, I want to execute some code only, when it is not a REST API request.

So I was looking for a command like `is_rest()` in order to do something like

```
<?php
if( ! is_rest() ) echo 'no-rest-request';
?>
```

But I couldn't find something like this. Is there a `is_rest()` out there?

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on what you want to do when it's not a REST request? The type of request isn't determined until query parsing, which happens after `init`. Also note that the parts of the API can be used internally on requests that aren't REST requests, so you risk breaking something if you are relying on that detection.

Comment: Thanks a lot you both. @birgire: Can you post this as an answer, so I can check it. Basically, it is the answer to my question :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a good point by @Milo, the `REST_REQUEST` constant is [defined](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8e41746cb11271d063608a63e3f6091a8685e677/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L135-L141) as `true`, within `rest_api_loaded()` if `$GLOBALS['wp']->query_vars['rest_route']` is non-empty.

It's [hooked](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8e41746cb11271d063608a63e3f6091a8685e677/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L364-L367) into `parse_request` via:

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'rest_api_loaded' );
```

but `parse_request` fires later than `init` - See for example the Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request).

There was a suggestion (by Daniel Bachhuber) in ticket [#34373](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34373) regarding `WP_Query::is_rest()`, but it was postponed/cancelled.

Comment: [#42061](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42061) might add `wp_is_rest_request()` or `wp_doing_rest()`.

Answer (score 21):

Just stumbled over the same problem and wrote a simple function `is_rest` that allows you to check if the current request is a WP REST API request.

```
<?php

if ( !function_exists( 'is_rest' ) ) {
    /**
     * Checks if the current request is a WP REST API request.
     *
     * Case #1: After WP_REST_Request initialisation
     * Case #2: Support "plain" permalink settings and check if `rest_route` starts with `/`
     * Case #3: It can happen that WP_Rewrite is not yet initialized,
     *          so do this (wp-settings.php)
     * Case #4: URL Path begins with wp-json/ (your REST prefix)
     *          Also supports WP installations in subfolders
     *
     * @returns boolean
     * @author matzeeable
     */
    function is_rest() {
        if (defined('REST_REQUEST') && REST_REQUEST // (#1)
                || isset($_GET['rest_route']) // (#2)
                        && strpos( $_GET['rest_route'], '/', 0 ) === 0)
                return true;

        // (#3)
        global $wp_rewrite;
        if ($wp_rewrite === null) $wp_rewrite = new WP_Rewrite();
            
        // (#4)
        $rest_url = wp_parse_url( trailingslashit( rest_url( ) ) );
        $current_url = wp_parse_url( add_query_arg( array( ) ) );
        return strpos( $current_url['path'] ?? '/', $rest_url['path'], 0 ) === 0;
    }
}
```

References:

- https://gist.github.com/matzeeable/dfd82239f48c2fedef25141e48c8dc30
- https://twitter.com/matzeeable/status/1052967482737258496

Comment: I didn't get what #3 did.

Comment: This is the best function for wordpress ever written on stackoverflow. Needed to use this for a `pre_get_posts` hook that ignores rest requests and worked like a charm.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand what's wrong with a popular plugin who copied your 2018 code but never caught the (very important) change you made in 2022! Well done :-) Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 11):

If you need it after `init` has fired:

`defined('REST_REQUEST') && REST_REQUEST`

If you need it before `init`, there are two ways:

Use `wp_is_json_request()` (Introduced in WordPress 5.0), or try to infer if it's a REST Request through the URL. Detecting the URL will vary whether the site is using permalinks or plain permalinks.

WooCommerce does it like this, and it's a good solution:

```php
function is_rest_api_request() {
    if ( empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {
        // Probably a CLI request
        return false;
    }

    $rest_prefix         = trailingslashit( rest_get_url_prefix() );
    $is_rest_api_request = strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $rest_prefix ) !== false;

    return apply_filters( 'is_rest_api_request', $is_rest_api_request );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Two options here really,

1. Check if `REST_REQUEST` is defined.
2. Hook into [`rest_api_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_api_init/) where you wanted to hook into `init`.

Comment: If you are using WP version 4.4.0+ (which you probably are), this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

To solve this problem I wrote a simple custom function based on the assumption that if the URI being requested falls under the WordPress site's Rest API URL, then it follows that it's a Rest API request.

Whether it's a valid endpoint, or authenticated, is not for this function to determine. The question is this: is the URL a potential Rest API url?

```
function isRestUrl() {
    $bIsRest = false;
    if ( function_exists( 'rest_url' ) && !empty( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] ) ) {
        $sRestUrlBase = get_rest_url( get_current_blog_id(), '/' );
        $sRestPath = trim( parse_url( $sRestUrlBase, PHP_URL_PATH ), '/' );
        $sRequestPath = trim( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/' );
        $bIsRest = ( strpos( $sRequestPath, $sRestPath ) === 0 );
    }
    return $bIsRest;
}
```

If your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` isn't properly populated, this function will still return `false`, regardless.

There is no hard-coding of the URL so if you for some reason change your API URL base, this will adapt.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not right, but I ended up with

```
if (strpos($_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-json/') !== false) {
    // Cool API stuff here
}
```

Feel free to let me know if this isn't right. Trying to make a helpful plugin starter to eventually share: https://gitlab.com/ripp.io/wordpress/plugin-starter

Comment: I think, this would fail, if you would not have pretty permalinks active.

Comment: You are definitely correct

Comment: Ok it requires pretty permalink... but who doesn't want it !!!?  This seems to me the safest way to do this.  All other solutions are fancy but over time if you want your code to still run on later wp versions... this seems to me a safe way !!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wp_is_json_request()` like below:

```
if ( wp_is_json_request() ) {
    // do you stuff here
}
```

Make sure that you set `Accepts` or `Content-Type` as `application/json` otherwise `wp_is_json_request()` will return false.

More Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_json_request/