# How would I know if my system using REST api or not?

Tags: rest-api

I have been using a wordpress site. For a reason I need to know if there is rest api is being used or not. Anyone can say how to check it please?

Comment: Visit `https://<yoursite>/wp-json/`. It'll show you the rest API endpoints.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "if there is rest api being used"? Do you mean that it is available or if there really are some requests done by the site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rest api - Does something like is_rest() exist](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221202/does-something-like-is-rest-exist)

Answer (score 1):

You can find it simply Go to the network tab of the browser’s developer tools, and see if it makes any AJAX requests.

If it does, and that response includes pure data, then that is an API.

Comment: Yyy. No, that means that this site uses some AJAX requests. These requests can use REST API, or admin-ajax.php (which is not REST API) or some other custom method of processing them (it's not recommended, but some plugins do it anyway).

Comment: Thanks! I got it