# Detect if REST API is running

Tags: rest-api

Many times I have code and I want to make sure it only runs in a rest api context, or it never runs in a rest context.

I know there are some hooks, but is there a function similar to `wp_is_doing_cron`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use :

```
if ( defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) && REST_REQUEST ) {...}
```

Source: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/926#issuecomment-162920686

If you take a look to [this source code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5f62cd1566d27be22d961c2a9af31f077efdecf7/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L329) on  you will notice the constant is defined before processing anything, I would check for it instead of calling the mentioned function `wp_is_json_request()`

Why?
if headers were not set when you do the check, it will return false, here is a real example reported for a GET request: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/11327

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `wp_is_json_request()` can be used to determine if the current request is a REST API request

> Checks whether current request is a JSON request, or is expecting a JSON response.
>
> *Official docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_json_request/*

Comment: That won't work for every case, I would use : `if ( defined( 'JSON_REQUEST' ) && JSON_REQUEST )` 
 Source: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/926#issuecomment-162920686

Comment: @Pabamato which cases won't it work for? Perhaps that should be an answer?

Comment: I think @Pabamato meant to use `REST_REQUEST` and not `JSON_REQUEST`.

Comment: Also, the answers [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221202/does-something-like-is-rest-exist) might also help you.

Comment: @TomJNowell if headers were not set when you do the check, it will return false, here is a real example reported for a GET request: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/11327. If you take a look to the source on https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L291 you will notice the constant is defined before processing anything, I would check for it instead of calling the mentioned function

Comment: Could that be added as an answer?

Comment: Done @TomJNowell, thank you and glad to help/contribute

Comment: FWIW, it worked in my case; `REST_REQUEST` wasn't defined (yet? I'm using it in a theme's functions.php for some yucky timezone juggling)